# Leaflet Marker Pop-Up Not Working on Kindle

Tags: android, leaflet, kindle-fire, kindle

I use Leaflet in a WebView for offline maps in several apps. It works fine on all my devices. Except on a Kindle Fire HD 6 (4th generation) the marker pop-up rarely display. I keep clicking on the marker and nothing happens. Once in a while, with no pattern, it does show the pop-up. The pop-up works fine on all other devices. What could be wrong?

```
var i = L.icon({iconUrl:"marker.png", iconSize:[100,100], iconAnchor:[50, 50]});
var m = L.marker([lat,lon],{icon:i});
m.bindPopup("HEY");
m.addTo(map);
```

You can download the whole Android Studio project here:

https://github.com/tomkincaid/LeafletTest